# Linux kernel - issues with Intel Pentium g4400 gpu drivers

Tags: linux, xorg, drivers, graphics, intel

I tried to install both **Debian** and **Ubuntu** last versions as virtual machines, but I couldn't use neither because of an **issue** with my **Intel Pentium g4400**. The fact is that Debian gives a **white error screen** with something like ***Something has gone wrong*** etc, while Ubuntu apparently loads the GUI but has **several bugs**. Only **terminal mode** worked properly. In the past, when I had an Intel Duo Core Duo, there wasn't any problem. What I have thought is that there are no **drivers** available for my Pentium g4400 gpu, the hd510 graphics series, but obviously I wish I'm wrong. Anybody can help me?

**EDIT :** I've just installed ubuntu 13.04 (32-bit) and I have no problems with the graphics. The only thing is that it's a bit slow but I think it's normal. However I run it on VirtualBox, Windows 10 10.0.14393, 8GB DDR4 RAM, Pentium g4400.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same processor and Openmandriva LX 3 works fine, the only problem is it´s too slow to start (I have installed in a SATA HDD).

I tried Manjaro, freya, Mint and Opensuse and it didn´t work, I guess the problem is the kernel version, Openmandrive use 4.6.5.

Comment: I'll try tu run a linux system with that kernel version then